# moc'ing 'Undefined interface' with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt, include, moc

I have slight problem with moc generation.

When I generate with VS2015-64bit I obtain the error `Undefined interface`. When I launch manually `moc.exe file.h` I obtain the same error. But when I launch `moc.exe file.h -I"include/path` all works fine

How can I add include path for moc'ing in VisualStudio ?

Thank,

Sébastien

Edit:
I change all include paths to `#include "../../../include/headerFile.h"` but is not a good solution.

Comment: Are you using the Qt add-in for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your path to project`s Additional Include Directories, something like "$(SolutionDir)/Include"

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with Visual Studio 2017.
The problem was that the include path for the Meta-Object Compiler was missing. And so it could not find the includes-files.
To solve this i had to add it under:

**Project-settings->Qt Meta-Object Compiler-> Include Path**

This is a really bad compiler warning since it should warn about not finding the included file.